# How to split text into sentences

Tags: java, regex

I need to split text into sentences. I have pattern

`(?<=[.!?]|[.!?]['"])(?=\p{javaWhitespace}*\p{javaUpperCase})`.

But it splits sentence like `Max (v. Village) - programmer.` into two senteces `Max (v.` and `Village) - programmer.`, but I expected one sentence. Too many examples:

`I am Max. I am 19.` -> `I am Max.`,  `_I am 19`

`She likes him(Dr. Web). Abc.` -> `She likes him(Dr. Web).`,`_Abc.`

not `She likes him(Dr.`, `_Web).`, `_Abc.`.

I tried to complete my regex to check bracket sequences, but failed.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Can you add some more sample text that you intend to split into sentences with expected vs actual output? I can see that you don't want to split your sentence from a dot that is inside a parenthesis but more data will help strengthening your regex.

Comment: I do not fully understand the problem here, in case this works you also can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29 Split with limit

Comment: Just write a parser and avoid regexes for that, it will be way easier to extend and improve the sentence recognition algorithm over time.

Comment: Do you just want to keep text inside parentheses together? Or is this also a sentence- `My name is Dr. Web.` ?

Comment: @plalx you are right, but it's good example for learn Special constructs of Pattern.

Comment: @rustyx your example is advanced. It's good for me to split him for two sentences. I want to correctly split sentences with brackets.

Comment: So what's the algorithm that you want? Split on punctuation, unless within parenthesis, brackets or quotes?

Comment: For a basic case, if you like to check brackets in regex you need to escape it using "\("  You may need to use "\\(" based on your language, since back-slash itself should also be escaped to be recognized as literal character.

Comment: @plalx yes. I'm interested how to do it with pattern at least for sentences with single brackets

Comment: @AlvinMax: Why do you have underscore before your second split-ed sentence? Is that intentional and you really need them or just splitting the sentence is good enough?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I don't want lose spaces. It's work with my pattern. I really need to fix problem with brackets.

Comment: @AlvinMax: While splitting, if you split by zero width match, then you will not loose anything. But that will introduce extra space before the second sentence which may be undesirable. So if you want to get rid of that extra space, splitting can be done consuming spaces that match as per your regex. Let me post an answer, and there you can let me know if you need me to change anything further.